Cheesy comedy about two guys on vacation who wreak havoc in a hotel
I remember watching this quite a while ago, so I'm pretty sure it's a pre-2000 film.
The plot involves two guys who go on a vacation to a hotel and then cause all sorts of mischief.
One of them starts having an affair with the wife of some rich man and a running gag involves the guy pretending to be someone else when the husband catches him around: first he pretends he is a barber and the husband asks for a haircut but the guy botches it which results in the husband wanting to kill him; the husband tries to hide his hair for the rest of the film. Then there's a fashion parade or something like that and this guy dresses as one of the females models called "The Black Widow"; the husband gets chosen to escort the Black Widow down the runway and realizes half-way it's the "barber" and tries to kill him again. Another one involves the guy laying over the man's wife in bed, with the covers over but one leg sticking out and the husband thinks that's his wife's leg and makes a comment on how she should shave her legs.
The other guy gets involved with some hippie-girl who invites him to her apartment and she does some weird meditation with candles and plants. There are also some sequences of people running and chasing each other through the hotel and one of the older ladies keeps shouting that the husband character is a pervert.
I thought Rob Schneider (sounds like his kind of movie, doesn't it?) or Billy Cristal would be in this movie but from looking at the titles they've been in it doesn't seem like. The husband character looks sort of like Billy Cristal.

This is Private Resort from 1985 starring the very young Johnny Depp and Rob Morrow as teenagers in a Miami resort. Morrow keeps running into a jewel thief called the Maestro (Hector Elizondo) and his wife. In one scene, Morrow poses as a barber and gives the Maestro a terrible haircut (shaving his hair down the middle); in another he poses as a runway model called the Merry Widow and the Maestro hits on him. The "hairy leg" scene is also there, and there's also a spiritual woman calling herself Hali Zumba who seduces Morrow with a candle. You can find some pics in this recap. Here's the trailer [slightly NSWF]:




Yup, that was the one. Funny how you remembered even the little details like the Merry Widow - now that you mentioned it, I remember it too.

"Remembered", "traumatized", it's a fine line. ;) Glad you found it.
